# Can GPM be used in a teminal emulator?

Tags: terminal, gentoo, gpm

I noticed it when installing gentoo

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GPM

But I can't figure out of it's possible to get it to work outside of a tty.

I'm using GNOME-Terminal if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really.  The library checks if it's running in "xterm" (by checking the `TERM` variable), and if so, just assumes that the application knows how to work with the xterm mouse protocol.

With ncurses, gpm is something of a nuisance outside of its use in the Linux console.  There are few applications which use it in a terminal emulator.

Further reading:

- [Nico Schottelius/ software/ gpm - general purpose mouse](http://www.nico.schottelius.org/software/gpm/)
- [Linking with GPM (Linux console mouse library)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#using_gpm_lib) (ncurses FAQ)
- [NEWS for ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html) (look for mention of gpm)